# UPDATE rows in a table that is _not_ partitioned but for which there _is_ a streaming buffer

Tags: google-bigquery

I am needing to update values in a table. The table is not partitioned. New inserts are being regularly (10s to 100s per hour) streamed to the table. This results in the constant presence of a streaming buffer for this table, yielding the following message when updates are attempted:

> UPDATE or DELETE statement over table `<project.dataset.table>`... would affect rows in the streaming buffer, which is not supported

None of the rows I am attempting to update are new and thus do not affect those inserts in the streaming buffer. Is there any way to successfully complete this update?

Comment: Please carefully pick a filter that guarantees to get only old (>30minutes) data. If you still see the error, fire a bug here: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: @YunZhang, this worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @yun-zhang pointed out in his comment, the solution was to carefully write the `WHERE` clause such that only old data (>30 minutes) would be affected by the update, which solves for the issue I was experiencing.